# Struggling to get Windows working in virtualbox with Ubuntu as the host

Tags: 14.04, windows, virtualbox

Desperately need help.
Hi Everyone

First thing that people are gonna have a problem with is why dont I ask the question on the virtualbox forum.
Well this is virtually (no pun intended) impossible. Every time I log in and want to ask a new question it says I must change my nick name for some reason. The site then does not accept the email that I just logged in with because it must sent my a verification. So ja this failed

The second thing people will say is that there is alot of stuff about this already asked.
My answer to that is I have tried every single thing and nothing works.

So please can someone help me.

I am running virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.04 as the host. System specs

Dell Latitude 5480
Memory 16GIG
Intel Core i7-7600 CPU
64Bit

I have set up Windows 10 on virtualbox with the Windows iso. When I start virtualbox it stays stuck on the windows logo. It does not further than this.

Any help please

Comment: Have you tried to boot into safe mode?

Comment: Can you please explain